# Виджет Pyqt5 Lcd не запускается время

Tags: python, pyqt5, виджет

Если запускать код виджета отдельно, он работает, а в проекте просто отображается, время не идет.

```
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, goldhunter.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.build_handlers()

    def build_handlers(self):
        self.startwork.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)

    def on_button_click(self):
        while keyboard.is_pressed("Esc") == False:

            for f in files:

                picture = "syndyk/" + f

                button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(picture, confidence = 0.95)

                if button:
                    pyautogui.click(button)
                    pyautogui.sleep(0.1)

class Tests(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)


    def showTime(self):
        self.current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        self.strCurrentTime = self.current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.strCurrentTime)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    form = Form()
    form.setupUi(window)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.